# New row not coming with table properties with Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I tried to add a new row in an existing table inside Google doc file but the table property is not applied to the new row. I was able to save 2 cells with styling. Here's the Apps Script function

```
function addRow(fileId)
{
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(fileId).getBody(),
        searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE),
        element = searchElement.getElement(),
        table = element.asTable();

    var cell1Style = table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getAttributes();
    var cell2Style = table.getRow(0).getCell(1).getAttributes();

    cell1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#ffffff';
    cell2Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#ffffff';

    var rowStyle = {};
    rowStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR] = '#000000';

    var tr = table.appendTableRow();
    tr.setAttributes(rowStyle);
    tr.appendTableCell('My Text:').setAttributes(cell1Style);
    tr.appendTableCell('My value').setAttributes(cell2Style);
}
```

Here's the document content after execution
[image: screenshot]

As you can see the new row came outside the table even though i have set border color attribute. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var table = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE).getElement().asTable();

  var newRow = table.appendTableRow();
  var lastRowAttributes = table.getRow(table.getNumRows()-1).getAttributes()

  newRow.appendTableCell("Text 1").setAttributes(lastRowAttributes);
  newRow.appendTableCell("Text 2").setAttributes(lastRowAttributes);
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, you can use:

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var table = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE).getElement().asTable();

  var lastRow = table.getRow(table.getNumRows()-1);

  var newRow = table.appendTableRow(lastRow.copy());

  newRow.getCell(0).setText("Text 1");
  newRow.getCell(1).setText("Text 2");
}
```

I decided to use the style of the last row (before appending) as the style for the following rows to save time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it didn't work.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7ja1lho5gti1xh/ScriptUpdate.jpg?dl=0
As you can see in the original attachment, i need different styling for first and second cell.
Also lastRowAttributes has these values when i added log,
{FONT_SIZE=null, ITALIC=null, STRIKETHROUGH=null, FOREGROUND_COLOR=null, MINIMUM_HEIGHT=0, BOLD=null, LINK_URL=null, UNDERLINE=null, FONT_FAMILY=null, BACKGROUND_COLOR=null}

Comment: @Mohammedshebin could you please share a cleaned-up version of your document so I can test it on the real problem?

Comment: Here it is
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1scqgARZ3t-w3qtQNM3GYWJ-LywY8Gk1VB9r6XWiik0s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello! I found out what your issue was! You have styled each cell, instead of the whole table. I have updated my answer to show how to get it to work in both cases.